# ssh: connect to host stopped working and port 22: connection timed out

Tags: networking, server, ssh, connection

I can not access to remote computer using `ssh username@host` anymore, it worked before then it stopped and I always get:

```
ssh: connect to host  port 22: Connection timed out
```

I checked firewall rules, nothing interrupting. I re-installed `ssh` server and made sure it is working but still the same problem.
I ping to the IP address and it is responding properly.

---

### I checked also ssh config and it is listening to port 22

Any help?

Comment: did you check in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` of the host computer which port is listened ?

Comment: yes and it is listening to Port 22

Comment: can you try to connect from other computer ? how are connected your network ? is there router ?

Comment: I will try to connect from another computer. But I do not understand what do you mean by is there router? I am trying to access my work station at the institute where I work from my laptop it worked before properly but then the connection stopped and timed out and I tried from another Internet connection and it is the same problem

Comment: did you try from other computer on the same network ? maybe the problem is in the different steps of your local network. I mean if your laptop is not physically directly link to your server, you should check everything place in the path between your laptop and your hostserver.

Comment: use `nmap -sS targetserver` on the host you connect from. Post your details here.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [SSH Server stops working after reboot, caused by missing /var/run/sshd](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1109934/ssh-server-stops-working-after-reboot-caused-by-missing-var-run-sshd)

Answer (score 0):

First of all check out if the SSH daemon is running properly. you may need to check the journald logs for further details.

You can alternatively run netstat command and see if SSH is listening on 22, and test if ‘telnet ip -port 22’ is working from the firewall to the machine ?

Check ssd_config configuration file if any restrictions in there.

Please note that any problem will be logged in the journald, the sshd.log or your firewall log.